# nginx won't start after updating GitLab

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, gitlab

I tried updating GitLab by running `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install gitlab-ce`. Everything seemed fine during the install, but after it finished, nginx stopped working and I can't get it to start.

After running: `sudo gitlab-ctl status`, I get this:

```
run: gitlab-workhorse: (pid 4378) 8613s; run: log: (pid 937) 9953s
run: logrotate: (pid 19116) 1412s; run: log: (pid 933) 9953s
down: nginx: 0s, normally up, want up; run: log: (pid 943) 9953s
run: postgresql: (pid 4456) 8581s; run: log: (pid 939) 9953s
run: redis: (pid 4466) 8581s; run: log: (pid 935) 9953s
run: sidekiq: (pid 4474) 8578s; run: log: (pid 940) 9953s
run: unicorn: (pid 4496) 8576s; run: log: (pid 931) 9953s
```

I tried running `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure` and rebooting. That didn't help. I also tried `sudo gitlab-ctl restart nginx`, which gave me this:

`timeout: down: nginx: 0s, normally up, want up`

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Was able to get nginx to start by changing the permissions of `/var/opt/gitlab` to 755. But I'm still getting ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when trying to load GitLab in my browser.

Comment: Nevermind. The above comment fixed it! Also had an SSL issue in gitlab.rb that was causing a problem.

Comment: Also, for anyone else, make sure to `sudo chmod 700 /etc/gitlab/ssl` if you're using SSL.

Comment: Read logs of nginx

Answer (score 3):

Try running `sudo gitlab-ctl tail` to view all errors.

I made a silly mistake of not creating certificates for the GitLab registry subdomain on my previous edit to my GitLab instance.

After viewing the errors, I found nginx was waiting to read the file and got stuck here:

> ==> /var/log/gitlab/nginx/current <==
>
> 2019-03-05_09:17:42.23918 nginx: [emerg] BIO_new_file("/etc/gitlab/ssl/registry.gitlab.xxx.com.crt") failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/etc/gitlab/ssl/registry.gitlab.xxx.com.crt','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)

All I can say is *facepalm*. I got it fixed after doing letsencrypt to fix my configuration.

Comment: You can get just the nginx ones with `sudo gitlab-ctl tail nginx`